# Is there an idiomatic equivalent for "Word cannot express how..."?

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, expressões-equivalentes, superlativos

I'm looking for idiomatic extreme superlative expressions for descriptions in Portuguese. English has a couple of commonly used turns of phrase that are used (almost as clichés) for this purpose.

> "Words cannot explain how confused I am"
>
> "I can't express how happy I am"
>
> "There are no words to describe how beautiful she is"

I've found myself saying things like

> "Eu não poderia nem expressar como agradecido eu estou pela ajuda de vocês."

for example.  But I have no idea if this is just my English brain "leaking" into Portuguese...

I'd be interested in answers that follow the literal meaning (i.e. *it's not possible to capture in words*) or ones that come from a different angle but are essentially idiomatic ways of saying "It's really really really [adjectivo]"

Comment: I just made an edit suggestion to your question. I see that you are an experienced SE user, so you must be familiar with the rollback function. If you disagree with the edit, hit the button.

Comment: There is a example in Roberto Carlos - Como é Grande o Meu Amor Por Você song. "[...] mas com palavras não sei dizer" :P

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence should be **"eu não sei como expressar o meu agradecimento pela ajuda de vocês".**

There are several different ways to convey what you mean. It pretty much depends on age, educational background and the degree of intimacy between the parts.

- Eu não tenho palavras para agradecer...
- Não sei como agradecer tudo aquilo que vocês...
- Galera, tô super-feliz e quero agradecer a surpresa que vocês...(young people, informal)
- Eu me sinto sem palavras para agradecer...
- Eu não tenho nem palavras para...
- Em um momento desses, é muito difícil que eu consiga palavras para expressar todo o meu...
- Me faltam palavras para descrever toda a beleza...
- Eu não sei se vou conseguir expressar em palavras o quão agradecido...("quão" is formal and old-fashioned)
- Não tenho palavras para descrever tudo o que estou sentindo.
- Não dá para descrever a beleza dela, nem com mil palavras.

**Perhaps the most usual form is "não sei como te agradecer".**

Comment: what's the specific problem with the example sentence I gave?  I looked on linguee and found a bunch of stuff like it, but a lot of that could also be bad translations from English http://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/search?source=auto&query=can%27t+express+how

Comment: @Some_Guy   "eu não poderia nem expressar" isn't idiomatic.  A native speaker would say "eu não sei nem expressar".  "como agradecido eu estou" sounds awkward.  I'd say "como eu estou agradecido".

Comment: @Some_Guy or "o quão agradecido estou", for a bit of nice formal hue.

Comment: "nem sei expressar o quão agradecido estou..."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can say in Portuguese that there are no words, or that you have no words, to express something ("Não há palavras", "não tenho palavras"). You can't say that "words fail", though. You may say that words cannot or do not express something ("palavras não podem expressar/dizer", "palavras não expressam/dizem"). Or you can say that words are not enough ("palavras não bastam" or "palavras são insuficientes" or "palavras não dão conta").

But you cannot translate "how" into "como" always; if it has a quantitave implication, it is probably better translated as "quanto" or "o quanto":

"*Eu não poderia nem expressar o quanto eu estou agradecido pela ajuda de vocês.*"

Also, fronting a predicative like in English ("how grateful I am") is not always trivial. Peculiarly, you can say "como eu estou agradecido", or "quão agradecido eu estou" but never "como agradecido eu estou").

---

Portuguese has synthetic superlatives, too:

"*Fico gratíssimo pela ajuda de vocês.*"

But their use is quirky (for instance, "agradecidíssimo" would be quite unusual, though the non-superlative "agradecido" is by far more common than "grato"), and standard and colloquial forms often diverge ("caríssimo" vs "carésimo").

The usual analytical way to express a superlative is through the adverb "muito" (much):

"*Estou muito agradecido.*"

And a few adverbs, including "muito", also accept synthetic superlatives, you can also say,

"*Estou muitíssimo agradecido.*"

But any adverb that can express intensification can be used, though with some implications on (in)formality:

"*Estou incrivelmente confuso.*"

"*Estou inacraditavelmente feliz.*"

"*Ela é tremendamente bela.*"

"*Estou super agradecido.*"

"*Estou fantasticamente apaixonado.*"

"*Estou fabulosamente impressionado.*"

"*Estou terrivelmente decepcionado.*"

Etc.